# jQuery DOM select only current DIV class

Tags: jquery, dom

I currently have a list of divs like this:

```
<div class="product_container">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <div id="add_product_img"></div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on the div with id `add_product_img`, this function runs

```
$('#add_product_img').click(function(){
    addImg()
});

function addImg(){
    var img = $('#multiple_product_featured_image').find('img').attr('src');
});
```

What I need is to have the `function addImg()` only seletc the img attribute of the `<div id="add_product_img"></div>` that was clicked and not any other divs.

I'm thinking of using the .this() selector but I'm not sure how should I apply it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` will be assigned to `this` inside the scope of the anonymous function fired by the `click` event handler.  Pass `this` to the `addImg` function and then traverse back to the parent and select the `img`.

```
$('#add_product_img').click(function(){
    addImg(this)
});

function addImg(elem){
   var img = $(elem).parent().find("img").attr('src');
});
```

I recommend traversing to the parent to prevent any issues that may occur if the markup changes.

Comment: Yep, your last recommendation is much better  :)

Answer (score 1):

First there should be only one class with a given id, so use class attribute to group similar elements

```
<div class="product_container">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <div class="add_product_img"></div>
</div>
```

then pass the clicked element reference to the `addImg` method as a parameter, then use the [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method along with the clicked element reference to find the target `img` element

```
$('.add_product_img').click(function(){
    addImg(this)
});

function addImg(el){
    var img = $(el).prev('img').attr('src');
});
```